# For what subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is $ $ Log$(\alpha^z) =z$Log$(\alpha) \ $ true?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

For what subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is the following true?

Log$(\alpha^z) =z$Log$(\alpha)$

where Log is the principal log, $z \ $ a complex variable and $\alpha$ a nonzero complex constant.

**EDIT (it seems my misconception is deep as the below actually seem false)**
I know that when the roles of $\alpha$ and $z$ are swapped, the equality holds. i.e.

Log$(z^{\alpha}) =\alpha$Log$(z),\ $ for $ \ z\in \mathbb{C}^*$,

is true.

I'm not so sure for the first.

Comment: why would it matter whether one is a variable and the other one is a constant? Variables take on values, like constants, so both expressions should be equally (in)valid. I agree with Stephen that the question is about the domain of validity.

Comment: @Lucozade Because variables behave differently to constants.  So, I don't think we can claim what you suggest (in general).

Comment: I cannot see your point; please elaborate. One would write $z^\alpha$ as $\exp(\alpha {\rm Log} (z))$, and similarly when roles of $z$ and $\alpha$ are swapped. Making a proper branch cut will lead to a unique complex value.

Comment: @Lucozade  I was actually using the identity z^a=exp(aLog(z))  to deduce the second identity in my question.  But if what you say is true, then this is not allowed, based on the counter example in José's answer.  This made me conclude that they must behave differently in this case.  But, why can't I make that deduction then?  That is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\alpha=-1+i$ and that $z=2$. Then:

- $\operatorname{Log}(\alpha^z)=\operatorname{Log}(-2i)=-\frac\pi2$;
- $z\operatorname{Log}(\alpha)=2\times\frac{3\pi}4=\frac\pi2$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Log}(\alpha^z)\neq z\operatorname{Log}(\alpha)$.

Comment: I think a better question should then be, *when* is it true? i.e. for what set of $z$?

Comment: Perhaps that it is a better question, but it's also *another* question. Did I answer the *current* question or not?

Comment: Yes, thanks. But somehow, I'm still unsatisfied.  I think what I really wanted to know was when is it valid (but I didn't realise it until now^^)

Comment: I've edited the question a little (sorry for the inconvenience).